# Is it possible to have more than one boost::asio::thread_pool in an application?

Tags: c++, boost, threadpool, boost-asio

Title says it all. I could not find this in the documentation. Is it safe to have more than one `boost::asio::thread_pool` instance in an application?

Comment: You should assume that any non-abstract class can be instantiated as many times as you want unless specified otherwise. That's kind of the whole point of classes.

Comment: Yes,  It can make sense to divide work across pools of threads. I usually have a single thread for IO and multiple for more significant "work"